# I deleted my appdata\roaming\apple computer\mobilesync\backup files and now I can't backup

Tags: backup

I deleted my `appdata\roaming\apple computer\mobilesync\backup` files.  Now I can't backup.

When I press **Back Up Now**, it waits a few seconds, then comes back and nothing is backed up.

How do I make it backup?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. Can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/288172/edit) your question to fully explain what you're doing and what you've already tried?

Answer (score 2):

Did you delete the Backup folder too? If so, if you recreate the Backup folder, you should be able to back up again :)

- Windows 8 and 10: In the Windows search bar type %appdata% (with the percents) and press return/enter. A file browser window will open to the Application Data folder. (or Roaming inside of Application Data)
- Windows 7, Vista, XP: From the start menu, select Run. In the run box, type %appdata% (with the percents) and press return/enter. A file browser window will open to the Application Data folder. (or Roaming inside of Application Data)
- From there, navigate to Apple Computer (creating if needed) > MobileSync (creating if needed), and then create the Backup folder again.

If that's not it, can you let us know what error you're seeing in iTunes, and what version of Windows you are on?

Comment: The Backup folder gets recreated.  Its there.  When I backup my IPAD PRO 10.5, it gets backed up, even after I deleted the folder mobilesync.  When I backup my Iphone5, it doesnt backup.  There is no error message.  There is no moving progress bar.  It just returns quickly, and the message "Your Iphone has never been backed up to this computer" is still there.  My iphone is set to not back up to the cloud. It is set to encrypt.

Comment: Three more questions: 1) What version of Windows are you running? 2) What version of iTunes are you running? 3) What version of iOS is on the iPhone 5?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating iTunes and see if it makes a difference. If not then relocate your backups (if you have any) to another folder on your desktop, then uninstall iTunes and then reinstall it, and then relocate the backed up files (if you have any).

Then test it again and see if it works.